# is there a way to detect a new line while iterating a string?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Lets say i have an **input** string like that:

```
var str = "hello i am a
robot, have a 
nice day";
```

and i am iterating the string like that:

```
let newTxt: string = "";
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == "\n") {
        // i want something like that...
        console.log("new line detected!");
    }
    newTxt += str[i];
}
```

I know its possible to detect new lines with `Regex` but i need to detect while iterating the string.
is there a way to detect new line while loop is executing?

Comment: You just did it.

Comment: does the above code not work? you could try using `===`?

Comment: You can `.exec`, but in this case you can `.split('\n')` the string and iterate the lines: `for(const line of str.split('\n')) { /* do something with line */ }`

Comment: That code will work if the input is valid, you need to use ` instead of " for multiline strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but:

```
var str = "hello i am a
robot, have a 
nice day";
```

Is not valid syntax.

Either escape (which doesn't create `'\n'`):

```
var str = "hello i am a\
robot, have a \
nice day";
```

Or use template strings (does create `'\n'`):

```
var str = `hello i am a
robot, have a 
nice day`;
```

Of course, you could also use `"` if you declared the `\n` yourself:

```
var str = "hello i am a\nrobot, have a\nnice day";
```

Otherwise **your code is OK**.

Template string demo (removed the type in `newTxt: string` so you can run it here):

```js
var str = `hello i am a
robot, have a 
nice day`;

let newTxt = "";
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == "\n") {
        // i want something like that...
        console.log("new line detected!");
    }
    newTxt += str[i];
}
```

Demo with escaping (notice it never prints `new line detected!`):

```js
var str = `hello i am a\
robot, have a \
nice day`;

let newTxt = "";
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == "\n") {
        // i want something like that...
        console.log("new line detected!");
    }
    newTxt += str[i];
}
```